# Numbers formating

Tags: typescript, format, numbers

I need to compare 2 values in typescript. One from database and one from UI.

```
UI:       1,026.586
Database: 1026586009.12572
```

This database number is somehow converted to the one from UI.
Can you give me a hand how to compare it? (or how to convert the databse number to the same as it is in UI?)

What I was able to achive is:

```
const x =1026586009.12572
let y = Math.round(x/1000);
y = y.toLocaleString();
```

but it gives me: y = 1,026,586 which is something different :(

Comment: Have you tried dividing 1 billion by 1 million, rather than 1 thousand? i.e. `let y = x / 1_000_000;`

Comment: With a `,` that UI "number" is a string and not a number. If you want to compare strings, you need to resolve the scaling issue first then use the exact same string formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

```
y = (x/1000000).toLocaleString()
```

Above did the job for me.